# iOS: Resizing popover dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I have an `UIViewController` that is presented as a popover. I set `preferredContentSize` in `viewDidLoad` and it works well.
I would like to add elements to the popover dynamically and i am looking for a way to resize the whole popover.
I tried resetting `preferredContentSize` but it does not seem to have any effect after at this point.
Is there a way to resize the popover dynamically?

---

I looked at the solutions suggested in the comments, but they require the use of contentSizeForViewInPopover, which is deprecated since ios 7

Comment: Have you taken a peek at this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16549488/4475605

Comment: These answers are not helpful - contentSizeForViewInPopover is deprecated since ios 7

Comment: post some code , if possible

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8516736/how-to-dynamically-change-the-contentsize-of-uipopovercontroller this doesnt help?